# Cannot find Shrink One Page command in Word for Mac 2016

Tags: macos, mac, microsoft-word, microsoft-office, system-preferences

I'm using Word for Mac 2016 version 16.15.

Apparently the `'Shrink One Page'` command should be in found in `Word Preferences > Ribbon & Toolbar`, but there's no sign of it there. See below screenshot.

Where is the `'Shrink One Page'` command?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

On my system it is listed under All Commands, so try looking there.

I am running an Insider Fast release 16.16, so if you don't find it on your version with 16.15, then it is coming soon.